# Motor pump slowed down due to suction blockage

Tags: motor, ac, short-circuit, coil, winding

I have a 1 HP, 220V motor pump which was working fine till recently. Last day, some dirt and dried leaves got into the foot valve and blocked the suction pipe. I ran the pump for sometime in that condition. After a few minutes my MCB tripped off indicating a short circuit. The motor casing appeared to be unusually hot. Thereafter, when  i turn on the pump, its running at a very slow speed and not sucking water. After a few 30 seconds it gets hot and my MCB would trip off. I have no clues what is happening. Can somebody tell me if my coil would have burned off? I am not sure what kind of motor it is using.

Comment: Did you attempt to clear the blockage?

Comment: Yes. The suction was cleared, i removed the pump from the installed basement after cutting off the pipes.

Answer (score 1):

All 220v water pumps I've worked with to date used induction motors. Assuming this is the case with your motor, the slower the spindle speed, the more current flows through the motor, thus explaining both the case heating and the MCB tripping (an induction motor whose spindle is stopped from moving at all effectively appears as a "dead short" to the input power supply). As for the slower operation after the initial overload problem, you may have damaged the motor start/run capacitor, or overheated/damaged a bearing or seal, causing a loss of efficiency/increase in drag, causing the now too slow speed & the resulting continued overcurrent & heating problems.

Comment: This assumes a single phase induction motor, likely a good assumption. One or both of the windings may have shorted turns. My guess is shorted turns is most likely, bad capacitor second, bad bearing third. It is also likely that two or more items have failed or are about to fail.

Comment: Given the 220v rating, it's fairly safe to assume single-phase internationally, similar to safely assuming split-phase for 110v, sinc "standard" 3 phase where each phae (L to N/L to GND) is 220v, is usually rated/described as 380-450V.

Comment: Robherc, your assumption is right. It's a single phase induction motor. I have removed the motor from the pump and tried running. That didn't help. The bearings are working fine. As @CharlesCowie has mentioned, i believe that a part of the coil has lost its enamel coating due to overheating. Which is causing a short circuit in the coil. Can i get it working by pouring some warnish/enamel over the coil? If the capacitor has been damaged, does the motor heats up and trips the circuit breakere?

Comment: @AjithMemana I have a single-phase (120V) induction motor that used to run a 14-inch disc sander. It worked very well until the motor start capacitor  went out. Then it would only turn slowly, with very little torque, humm & heat up (until it melted enough enamel to short a coil). You can try to test/replace the cap on yours, but if there's a short in the coil (likely welded) I wouldn't bother trying to get fresh enamel to "find" and eliminate the short. It's probably time to have it re-wound, or just buy a replacement (likely less expensive).